# How to get rid of beamer automatic numbering?

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I am creating a presentation on beamer and the footpage is automatically numbering the slides. I would like to get rid of that numbering in all the slides but I only found partial solutions for specific slides so far.

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}` may work if you are using one of the standard themes

Comment: I am using Madrid theme. I tried your solution but seemed not to work

Answer (score 1):

The following works with beamer version >= 3.49. If it does not work for you, please update your beamer version.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]